# docker deploy nuxtjs application error code 100

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, deployment, nuxt.js

I'm deploying NuxtJs project to live server but getting error

E: Unable to locate package tini

{"code":100,"message":"The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y tini' returned a non-zero code: 100"}

The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && apt-get install -y tini' returned a non-zero code: 100
Build has failed!

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.15.1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=TRUE
RUN apk add --no-cache su-exec

# create destination directory

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/nuxt-app
WORKDIR /usr/src/nuxt-app

# update and install dependency

RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN apk add git

# copy the app, note .dockerignore

COPY . /usr/src/nuxt-app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NUXT_HOST=127.0.0.1
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

CMD \[ "npm", "start" \]

# Set any ENVs

ARG BASE_URL=${BASE_URL}
ARG BASE_URL_WITHOUT_API=${BASE_URL_WITHOUT_API}
ARG NUXT_ENV_BASE_URL=${NUXT_ENV_BASE_URL}
```

Comment: Which OS are u using?

Comment: @RichardRublev It's ubuntu: 20

Comment: I don't see any mention of `tini` in this Dockerfile; are you sure this is the same Dockerfile you used in local testing?  (I see several issues, including mixed `apt-get` and `apk` and an incorrect `CMD` syntax, but nothing related to `tini`.)  When you do deploy this, can you push a built image to a registry, rather than rebuilding it on the target system?